# how to set up a cron job twice a day to save what was installed using sudo apt-get install to a text file

Tags: cron

using this command I save all the `sudo apt-get install` to a text file:
`history | grep "sudo apt-get install" | sed 's/^ *//' | cut -d' ' -f3- > ~files/packages/installed_on_raspberrypi.txt`

how can I make a cron job that it should run twice a day in morning and in the end of the day ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of etckeeper is a very good idea.

However, to get a list of all installed (and deinstalled) packages, you should use: `dpkg --get-selections`. This gives you all packages that should be installed and uninstalled on your system.

If you ever want to reinstall a system according to this list you do: `dpkg --set-selections < /path/to/file` and then run `apt-get dselect-upgrade`

If you want to see what was when installed and/or uninstalled you have the logfile: `/var/log/dpkg.log`

Using the `history` command might not reveal everything that you have installed, since it does not save a great bunch of commands, except of course you set it longer. `man history` gives you more information on that.

Answer (score 2):

While not a text file nor using chron, you can use a combination of git and etckeeper to achieve the same result.

> etckeeper allows the contents of /etc to be stored in a Version
>   Control System (VCS) repository. It integrates with APT and
>   automatically commits changes to /etc when packages are installed or
>   upgraded. Placing /etc under version control is considered an industry
>   best practice, and the goal of etckeeper is to make this process as
>   painless as possible. - from the [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/etckeeper.html)

Start by installing git:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Configure git for the root account:

```
sudo git config –global user.name “Your Name”
sudo git config –global user.email youremailaddress
```

Then install etckeeper:

```
sudo apt-get install etckeeper
```

Because git is already installed this will not only install etckeeper, but initialize the database and make an initial commit of the files in /etc.

You can check the status of the repository with the following commands:

```
cd /etc
sudo git status
```

you should see the following:

On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Now anytime you run an apt command (install, purge etc.) Etckeeper will automatically add a commit to the underlying git repo, noting the changes and time they were made.

You can view all packages installed, updated and removed using the git log command.

```
cd /etc
sudo git log
```

As I mentioned this is not a text file, but the git log can certainly be turned into a text file if needed. This also has the advantage of being automatic and tracking any changes made manually to your systems config files.

I wrote a blog post with additional details and some config settings you may want to make available [here](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/146996830774/tracking-your-systems-configuration-changes-with).

Comment: Thanks git is the right way to go , performing auto commit will also track when the package was added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47004/discussion-between-steve-robillard-and-goldilocks).